# C++ deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined

Tags: c++, types, c++17

Calculator.h

```cpp
class Calculator {
    Calculator();
    template<typename... Args>
    static auto add(Args... args);
};
```

Calculator.cpp

```cpp
#include "Calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator() {}

template<typename... Args>
auto Calculator::add(Args... args) {
    return (args + ... + 0);
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Calculator.h"

int main(){
    Calculator cal;
    std::cout<< cal.add(1,2,3);
}
```

> Function 'add<int, int, int>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined

If I move the `add()` method into the header file, there is no error.  What am I missing?

Comment: `auto` requires definition... main.cpp doesn't have it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: In main.cpp, you need to know what the type of `cal.add(1, 2, 3)` is. How do you determine that?

Comment: @Mat: same problem (but indeed same solution) for non template function with `auto` return type.

Comment: @Mat thanks for sharing the link. same problem like @ Jarod42 mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I'm missing?

The error message explains it: You're trying to use a deduced return type before the function is defined. That is not allowed<sup>1</sup>. To clarify, you call the function `Calculator::add` in `main`, but the function `Calculator::add` is not defined in the same translation unit before the function call. In fact, it is not defined in the same translation unit at all.

You need to either:

1. Define the function before calling it, which is what you did when you defined the function in the header,
2. or declare the return type explicitly without auto-deduction... However, there is still another, unrelated but similar problem in your example program if you use this approach: Templates cannot typically be instantiated before they have been defined. 1. Approach fixes this problem as well.

<sup>1</sup> This is not allowed because the return type is deduced based on the return statements in the function definition. If there is no function definition, then there is no way for the compiler to figure out the return type.

Comment: Can you explain how he's using it before it's defined?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Added more explanation.